# Получение значения куки

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте есть функция добавления постов в избранные. Для хранения использую куки. Сохранение происходит так, на станице где находятся все посты
получаю `id` поста который нужно сохранить и с помощью `ajax` отправляю в файл обработчик, и сохраняю массив `$ads` таким образом:

```
setcookie('ads', serialize($ads));
var_dump($_COOKIE['ads']);
```

var_dump выводит

`a:6:{i:0;s:3:"174";i:1;s:3:"182";i:2;s:3:"178";i:3;s:3:"188";i:4;s:2:"31";i:5;s:3:"108";}`

На другой странице пытаюсь вывести:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['ads']))
{
    var_dump($_COOKIE['ads']);
}
```

Но, к сожалению, ничего не выводится( P.S. В качестве CMS использую WordPress, может он как-то блокирует.

Comment: WordPress использует куки в своём базовом функционале. Ничего он не блокирует.

Comment: Если setcookie() вызывается после того, как произведён вывод на экран, куки не установится. Это ограничение протокола http

Comment: @KAGG Design, Да вы правы. У меня файлы находятся в разных папках, может ли быть так что куки не работают из-за этого? Может есть смысл задать путь?

Comment: @KAGG Design, вывод в самом конце

Comment: При чем тут путь? У вас куки не установятся, если есть вывод до этого. Почитайте документацию по функции setcookie

Comment: @KAGG Design, про вывод я знаю. Поэтому написал `вывод в самом конце` т.е. `var_dump` после объявления функции `setcookie` . Указал время истечения и путь, `setcookie('ads', serialize($ads), time()+3600,'/'); `все заработало, но теперь почему-то на другой странице работает `var_dump($_COOKIE['ads']);` , но не работает  `var_dump(unserialize($_COOKIE['ads']));`. Где может быть ошибка?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69319/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-r-mcreal).